# Is there a way to retrieve tasks of project that contains an specific tag?

Tags: asana

I'm trying to build a query to retrieve the tasks of project that contains an specific tag.

I'm being able to retrieve the tasks of a project or to retrieve the tasks that contains an specific tag, however I wasn't able to find a way to combine those.

As workaround I'm retrieving all the tasks of the project and doing the filtering on my own; however that won't scale with a project with many many tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can filter by project OR by tag, but the Asana API does not yet offer a more advanced search or way of combining filters. I agree the best way to achieve this currently is to fetch the set of tasks by either project or tag, whichever set is smaller, and then do the filtering on your own.